# How to Write a Self Join Query

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have simple collection `transactions` which hold the information of user and restaurant

```
{ "user_id" : "U1", "restaurant_id" : "R_1" }
{ "user_id" : "U2", "restaurant_id" : "R_1" }
{ "user_id" : "U1", "restaurant_id" : "R_3" }
{ "user_id" : "U1", "restaurant_id" : "R_4" }
{ "user_id" : "U2", "restaurant_id" : "R_4" }
```

Here I need to find related restaurant between users having user_id **U1** and **U2** (i.e I want to find those restaurant where **U1** and **U2** both have visited)

I should received the output like this:-

```
{ "_id" : "R_4", "users" : [ "U2", "U1" ] }
{ "_id" : "R_1", "users" : [ "U2", "U1" ] }
```

That mean restaurant **R_1** and **R_4** has been visited by both user **U1** and **U2**

I'm new to mongoDb so after googling I have written sample query which is not working

```
db.transactions.aggregate([
    {$match: {"user_id": {
        "$in": [ U1, U2]
    }}},
    {
        $lookup: {
           from: "transactions",
           localField: "restaurant_id",
           foreignField: "restaurant_id",
           as: "related_taste"
         }
    }
])
```

Comment: Also, are you trying to "join" to the **same** collection? That's an RDBMS concept that does not really apply here. And generally speaking there are better ways to do that.

Comment: @NeilLunn so can you let me know what is best method to do this

Comment: yes I was applying same logic as I do in Mysql because I have good understanding in Mysql but I'm new to Mongo so I don't known what is the best practice to handle this kind on situation

Comment: Yes. Since this isn't SQL we issue the statements a little differently. You "could" use `$lookup` here, but it really is not necessary as well as being an overhead we don't need as well. There is another way.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What you want is the "union" of results, which goes like this:

```
db.transactions.aggregate([
    { "$match": { "user_id": { "$in": [ "U1", "U2" ] } }},
    { "$group": {
      "_id": "$restaurant_id",
      "users": { "$addToSet": "$user_id" }
    }},
    { "$match": { "users": { "$all": [ "U1", "U2" ] } } }
])
```

Which gives the output:

```
{ "_id" : "R_4", "users" : [ "U2", "U1" ] }
{ "_id" : "R_1", "users" : [ "U2", "U1" ] }
```

How this works is that the [`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) stage accumulates on the `restaurant_id` values and retains the "set" via [`$addToSet`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/addToSet/) of the `user_id` values that were present for that grouping key.

Then we [`$match`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/) again using the [`$all`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/all/) condition to see that "both" the supplied `user_id` values were present in the restaurants that we gathered the "set" for.

So any places visited by only "one" of the listed users are discarded, and we get the results that are just those visited by both.

---

Given a correction on your data:

```
{ "user_id" : "U1", "restaurant_id" : "R_1" }
{ "user_id" : "U2", "restaurant_id" : "R_1" }
{ "user_id" : "U1", "restaurant_id" : "R_3" }
{ "user_id" : "U1", "restaurant_id" : "R_4" }
{ "user_id" : "U2", "restaurant_id" : "R_4" }
```